# Gradle sync failed: The system cannot find the path specified Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

**Gradle sync failed**: The system cannot find the path specified
                Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

[image]

Comment: Please post a detailed gradle error log

Comment: You can find it at bottom right corner via tab named Gradle Console

Comment: Error:The system cannot find the path specified

Comment: Please check the gradle-wrapper.properties file in root of the project. Check the value of the 
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip

Comment: #Fri Oct 13 18:27:51 BDT 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.2.1-all.zip

Comment: thats looks ok. You can try to use gradlew from terminal/command prompt and paste it here ./gradlew assembleDebug  --stacktrace

Comment: Sorry! i don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `GRADLE_USER_HOME` or some configuration in AS is pointing to your  AS installation directory. This directory is in `C:\Program Files\` and thus by default only writable with elevated privileges. You are executing AS without elevated privileges of course and thus cannot write to that directory which is what the error message says.

Either change your configuration of `GRADLE_USER_HOME`, reinstall AS in a place where you have write permission, run AS with elevated privileges (I wouldn't recommend this) or make the directory writable without elevated privileges (I wouldn't recommend this either).

Answer (score 0):

I think the you Must Change the Location of you Gradle and Then Re-select it again and Reload your Android Studio/Close your Project and Open them Again..